# Visual Studio PC benchmark

Tags: visual-studio, hardware, benchmarking

Hi: Is there a good way to benchmark a Visual Studio developer PC, instead of looking at the technical specs? Objective is to set a level and see every developer passes, if not upgrade them to new PC. Any thoughts and suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about the built in [Windows System Assessment Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Assessment_Tool)? It has been part of windows since Vista.

From the linked article:

It currently assesses:

- Aero Assessment
- Direct3D Alpha Blending Assessment
- Direct3D Texture Load Assessment
- Direct3D ALU Assessment
- Windows Media Playback
- CPU Performance
- Memory Performance
- Disk Performance

Comment: +1 This about the best built-in baseline you have, the most important factors for VS in particular will be **Disk** and **CPU** performance.

Comment: And with VS 2010 using WPF, the graphics capabilities are also a factor.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like [CrystalMark](http://www.testmygeekstuff.com/download/view.download/3/3), it's a free benchmark and gives you an overall report of your system performance in actual measured values, not a Windows index.  It measures processor (integer and floating point), graphics (2D and 3D), memory, cache, and disk.